# PHP doesn't get $_FILES when sending form data using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, upload, multipartform-data

I'm trying to create an upload element on my website. What I'm trying to do is an upload button that instantly when the user picks a file from the computer it uploads it to the server.

This is my form:

```
<form id="createAlert" name="createAlert" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="createAlert.php">
    <input name="title" type="text" class="input-medium" maxlength="36"></input>

    <textarea name="content" rows="7" cols="90" class="input-short" style="font-family: arial; width: 80%; resize: none; height: 250px"></textarea>

    <input name="push" type="checkbox"></input>

    <input enctype="multipart/form-data" name="img" id="img" size="35" type="file"/>

    <input class="submit-gray" type="submit" value="POST ALERT"/>
</form>
```

Here is my Javascript code that sends the file as a `FormData` object to an upload page (`upload.php`):

```
    $('#img').live('change', function() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', $('#img')[0].files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url : 'upload.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : formData,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert(data);
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    });
```

So far, so good - everything works fine. The problem is with the `upload.php` file that receives the `FormData`. Here is it's code (It's only a testing version it doesn't upload the file yet):

```
<?php
print file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($_FILES);
var_dump($_POST);
```

The problem is that the output of `var_dump($_FILES);` and `var_dump($_POST)` is two empty arrays, while in the `file_get_contents('php://input')` I get the file data.

Here is the output (I cut out the part with the content of the uploaded file...):

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryw4nmFcISqYuAWQOS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Sem Título-1.png"
Content-Type: image/png

//Here is the file I uploaded...

------WebKitFormBoundaryw4nmFcISqYuAWQOS--
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
```

I read dozens of answers to questions here and many solutions to the problem I have but none of them solved the problem.

What am I doing wrong? Why am I receiving the file just in the php://input but not using `$_FILES`?

Thank you!

Comment: How old is the version of jQuery you're using? I ask as `live()` was deprecated and removed a *long* time ago

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Right now I'm using jquery 1.3.2 this is an old system and I'm just now upgrading it adding new features, I can update it but I didn't think it would cause this problem... Does it?

Comment: It certainly won't be helping. That version of jQuery is almost 10 years out of date.

Comment: try this `var formData    =   new FormData($("#createAlert")[0]); ` ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ok thank you, I will try updating and update you if it worked

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I will try that also and let you know if it helped

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Genius! It worked! I can't believe it was that, I've spent the past 5 hours on this stupid thing lol. Post it as an answer ;)

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you update the version of jQuery that you're using. `live()` was deprecated and removed from the source over 5 years ago now, and there have been several changes to the way data is serialised and encoded within `$.ajax()`.

It's possible the old version you're using doesn't have these updates and is not adding the FormData to the request in the correct manner.